# "heroku db:pull --exclude table_name" How to exclude more than one table?

Tags: database, heroku

I can't find anywhere how to use "--exclude".
When I try this code

```
heroku help db:pull
```

I get this:

```
Usage: heroku db:pull [DATABASE_URL]

 pull heroku data down into your local database

 DATABASE_URL should reference your local database. if not specified, it
 will be guessed from config/database.yml

 -c, --chunksize SIZE # specify the number of rows to send in each batch
 -d, --debug          # enable debugging output
 -e, --exclude TABLES # exclude the specified tables from the pull
 -f, --filter REGEX   # only pull certain tables
 -r, --resume FILE    # resume transfer described by a .dat file
 -t, --tables TABLES  # only pull the specified tables
```

ok I understand how to use "-e" with one table, but I want to exclude more than one table.
It is not working:

```
heroku db:pull -e users, versions
```

Comment: If I had to make an educated guess based on common command-line conventions I'd say `-e "users versions"`, but that's just one of several possibilities.  You definitely need quotes if there is a space in there for any reason, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It works for me

```
heroku db:pull -e "stats admins" --app APP_NAME
```

Comment: Looks like this is no longer supported?

Comment: No longer support, use --exclude-table-data

Comment: deprecated flag

Answer (score 6):

From the docs "Use ';' to split names"

`heroku pg:pull [DATABASE] --exclude-table-data "[FIRST_TABLE_NAME];[SECOND_TABLE_NAME]" --app [APP_NAME]`

Answer (score 0):

I just used

`heroku pg:pull  DATABASE_URL LOCAL_DB  --exclude-table-data TABLE_NAME  --app APP_NAME`

UPDATE: To exclude multiple tables try

`heroku pg:pull  DATABASE_URL LOCAL_DB  --exclude-table-data TABLE_1_NAME; --exclude-table-data TABLE_2_NAME --app APP_NAME`

try heroku pg:pull --help to get full documentation